# Finding Complex Numbers to Satisfy an Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Sorry I am back again so soon but I am struggling to understand the following question:

Find three complex numbers that satisfy the following equation: |z-2| = |z-3i|

So far I believe I have two correct solutions which are $z = \frac{-5}{4}$ and $1 +\frac{3i}{2}$

but I am at a loss on how to find the third solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You can ask anytime, Micheal! Anyway, for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). It will help make the question look a bit more neat!

Comment: I agree with the method of solving this, done by @labbhattacharjee. I just want to comment on "I had absolutely no idea that this was a straight line the whole time!" The question asks to find all $z$ that has the same distance to $2$ and $3i$. Draw a complex plane. Draw those points. What points have the same distance to these points? It must be a line, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$z=x+iy\implies$

$$(x-2)^2+y^2=x^2+(y-3)^2\iff4x-6y+5=0$$

So, any point of the straight line $4x-6y+5=0$ will satisfy this.

Choose arbitrary $x$ to find one corresponding $y$ OR vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes perfect sense. I had absolutely no idea that this was a straight line the whole time! Thanks again :)

Comment: @Michael, Welcome. Btw, how have you found the two solutions?

Comment: I got both of them by graphing them on the calculator, but they are strange looking graphs. One of them has an intersection at -5/4 and other one the same I just clicked find intersection and it was (1,3/2)

Comment: And I tried trial and error just kept putting numbers in to see if it worked.